# i need to open front camera in android . i am creating a mirror app. how can i open?

Tags: android, camera

This is the code i use in android studio to open front camera ... but i get "Camera" function deprecated help me !!!

```
private static final String TAG = null ;

private Camera openFrontFacingCamera()
{
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```

Comment: use camera2 instead camera. btw, are you using API 21? [read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you also added the following to your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

And if you are building on API 21 then you should look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html